# "Flickenteppich" - Bedeutung im Kontext

Tags: meaning-in-context

Aus aktuellen Nachrichten:

> Die Entscheidung hat Signalwirkung für viele andere Städte, deren Luft zu stark mit Stickoxiden belastet ist. Sie sieht Übergangsfristen und eine phasenweise Einführung von Fahrverboten vor. Außerdem solle es Ausnahmeregelungen etwa für Handwerker geben. Es gebe aber keine finanzielle Ausgleichspflicht. "Gewisse Wertverluste sind hinzunehmen", sagte der Vorsitzende Richter Andreas Korbmacher. **Die zuständigen Landesbehörden hätten es in der Hand, einen "Flickenteppich" zu verhindern**.

Dieser Text steht nahezu in allen großen Online-Zeitungen unverändert. Und ich kann nicht verstehen, was damit gemeint wird. Er passt ja gar nicht zu dem restlichen Text. Was wird hier mit "Flickenteppich" gemeint? Und was hat dieser "Teppich" mit Ausnahmeregelungen, Wertverlusten u.a. zu tun?

Comment: Zur einleitenden Ergänzung der bereits bestehenden Antworten und Klärung des Begriffs - Zitat [Wikipedia Flickenteppich](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flickenteppich): Im übertragenen Sinne werde auch alle Arten von Fragmentierung bzw. Zergliederung als Flickenteppich bezeichnet.

Comment: @mtwde Die Bedeutung kenne ich schon aus dem Zusammenhang "ÖPNV-Tariffe" :D Hier haben mich nun "Asugleichspflicht" und "Wertverluste" ein bisschen irritiert. Wäre der Satz vor dem "Es gebe aber keine...", dann wäre mir alles klar.

Comment: Zuerst mal ist die Unsitte zu tadeln, Metaphern in Anführungsstriche zu setzen. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vermutlich, dass jede Stadt/Gemeinde/Region unterschiedliche Regelungen bzgl. der Dieselfahrzeuge einführtt bzw. einführen könnte. Die Landesbehörden können/sollen eben dafür sorgen, dass in einem Bundesland überall die gleichen Regelungen zu dieser Thematik gelten.

Zumindest in Österreich habe ich den Begriff "Flickenteppich" im Zusammenhang mit regional unterschiedlichen Gesetzen durchaus schon gehört.

Comment: Kleine Spitzfindigkeit: Verkehr ist in D Bundesrecht, d. h. die (Bundes-)Länder können hier keine "Gesetze" erlassen.

Comment: Danke für den Hinweis, da fehlt mir als Österreicher das Detailwissen! Ich habe das einfach aus dem zitierten Text abgeleitet ("Die zuständigen Landesbehörden hätten es in der Hand...").

Answer (score 8):

Die **Städte** dürfen Fahrverbote verhängen, Ausnahmeregelungen treffen usw.

Das heißt, prinzipiell könnte jede Stadt selbst definieren, wer vom Fahrverbot betroffen ist und welche Ausnahmen gelten: in einer Stadt nur für Handwerker, in der anderen auch für Taxis usw.

Um diesen *Flickenteppich*, also dass in jeder Stadt andere Fahrverbote und andere Ausnahmen gelten, zu verhindern, sollte das jeweilige Bundesland eine einheitliche Regelung für alle Städte treffen.

Da ein Fahrverbot für gewisse Fahrzeuge bedeutet, dass diese in einer Stadt weniger nützlich sind, könnte jemand auf die Idee kommen, die betreffende Stadt für diesen Wertverlust in Regress zu nehmen. Das wird aber ausdrücklich ausgeschlossen.

Wie mtwde in einem Kommentar anmerkte, bedeutet der Flickenteppich im übertragenen Sinn

> alle Arten von Fragmentierung bzw. Zergliederung

(Quelle: [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flickenteppich#Trivia))

Answer (score 2):

Ich glaube, der *Flickenteppich* ist eines der wenigen Wörter, die aus ihrer Heimat in Österreich ausgebüchst sind, und sich jetzt in Deutschland breit machen. (In der Regel wandern Wörter in die umgekehrte Richtung: von Deutschland nach Österreich.)

Ein *Fleck* ist in Österreich nicht nur eine schmutzige Stelle, sondern auch ein kleines Stück Stoff. In Deutschland ist dafür der Begriff *Flicken* geläufiger. Ein kleiner *Fleck* ist ein *Fleckerl*.

Man kann viele solcher Flecken (die auf englisch *patches* heißen) zusammennäht, erhält man eine Patchworkdecke. Eine Decke ist aber kein Teppich.

Den Teppich bekommt man, wenn man viele Flecken in einem Webstuhl mit langen Schnüren verwebt. Die Schnüre laufen in Längsrichtung, die Flecken legt man quer dazu ein.

So ein Teppich heißt in Österreich *Fleckerlteppich* und in Deutschland offenbar *Flickenteppich.*

Das wesentliche Merkmal so eines Teppichs ist, dass er aus vielen kleinen Teilen zusammengesetzt ist, die ursprünglich nicht zusammengehörten, und dem Endergebnis ein uneinheitliches Aussehen verleihen.

Im übertragenen Sinn wird das Wort *Fleckerlteppich* in Österreich für zwei Dinge verwendet:

- für Straßen, die bereits oft ausgebessert wurden, und daher nun holprig sind.
- für Gesetze, Bestimmungen, Verordnungen usw., an denen schon viele Veränderungen und Ausbesserungen vorgenommen wurden, und die daher nun uneinheitlich wirken. (Das österreichische Schulgesetz ist ein typisches Beispiel für so einen Fleckerlteppich. Schon vor knapp 50 Jahren hat man erstmals beschlossen, es grundlegend zu reformieren, aber das geschah bisher nicht. Stattdessen wurde es von jeder Regierung in kleinen Portionen abgeändert, ohne eine klare Linie erkennen zu lassen.)

Ebenfalls als Fleckerlteppich wird der Zustand beschrieben, dass ein bestimmter juristischer Sachverhalt nicht in einem einzelnen Bundesgesetz geregelt wird, sondern (in Ö) in neun verschiedenen Landesgesetzen. Beispiele sind das Jugendschutzgesetz und die Bauordnung.

Wenn in dem zitierten Text gesagt wird

> Die zuständigen Landesbehörden hätten es in der Hand, einen "Flickenteppich" zu verhindern.

Dann ist damit gemeint, dass die Landesbehörden (zumindest theoretisch) in der Lage wären, ein einheitliches Gesetz ohne Ausnahmen und ohne regionale Unterschiedlichkeiten zu formulieren. Denn offenbar scheint in der Realität genau das nicht der Fall zu sein.

Ich habe diese Debatte in meinem Nachbarland Deutschland nur am Rande verfolgt, aber offenbar ist das neue Abgasgesetz entweder voller Ausnahmen oder hat regional unterschiedliche Gültigkeit. Es ist also nicht nicht *aus einem Guss* sondern das Gegenteil, nämlich ein *Flickenteppich* (*Fleckerlteppich* in Ö).

Comment: Bei aller (ernsthaften) Liebe zu Österreich und seinen vielfältigen kulturellen Hervorbringungen: Die These, dass das Wort *Flickenteppich* (z.B. als Fleckerlteppich) speziell von dort seinen Ausgang nahm und sich dann in andere Gefilde deutscher Zunge ausbreitete, bedürfte wohl zumindest noch einer argumentativen Unterfütterung. Ein  Flickenteppich ist ja ein universales Alltagskulturgut, das dürfte als Produktidee überall dort von selbst entstehen, wo man Stoffreste hat und seinen Boden bekleiden will, und somit würde dort auch ein Wort geprägt. Ich bin aber auf Argumente gespannt.

Comment: Oh, noch was. Es geht nicht um ein "neues Abgasgesetz". Es geht um die lange mit Spannung erwartete Entscheidung des Bundesverwaltungsgerichts, ob Städte rechtlich in der Lage sind, Fahrverbote für bestimmte Fahrzeuge zum Schutz der Luftqualität zu erlassen. Es hatte vorinstanzliche Urteile gegeben, die die Städte geradezu dazu zwingen würden, und die gestrige Entscheidung gibt nun Rechtssicherheit in dieser Richtung. Hat nichts zu tun mit einem neuen Gesetz, auch wenn die Bundesregierung jetzt allmählich in Zugzwang kommt, endlich ihren Schmusekurse mit der Automafia aufzugeben.

Answer (score 0):

Flickenteppich kommt aus der Zeit, als Deutschland noch aus vielen einzelnen Herzogtümern, Fürstentümern und Grafschaften bestand. Es ist ein Synonym für Kleinstaaterei.
Das wird eben auch gerne aufgegriffen, wenn die einzelenen Bundesländer für irgendeinen Bereich des gesellschaftlichen Lebens eigene Regelungen treffen dürfen.
Noch schwieriger ist es mit Bereichen, die auf kommunaler Ebene individuell sind.
Die Aussage von mtwde und IQV fasst das gut in einem Satz zusammen.

Mehr über den historischen Kontext: https://www.welt.de/print/wams/vermischtes/article13637662/Deutschland-ein-Flickenteppich.html

Comment: Du könntest präzisierend hinzufügen: "*Flickenteppich* **als Begriff der politischen Geographie**..." , denn das Wort Flickenteppich gab es ja schon früher: nämlich als Wort für einen ebensolchen.